# Detect iframe dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Inorder to check if an iFrame is currently open you can use:

```
if (window!=window.top) { /* I'm in a frame! */ }
```

But what if I want to get an alert when an iFrame opens? How can I allow JS to automatically detect an iFrame has been opened on the current page or inserted within the DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using JQuery you can with the following piece of code:

```js
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'iframe', function(e) {
  console.log("Iframe inserted into document");
});

// To test it
$('button').click(function() {
  $('body').append('<iframe></iframe>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add iframe</button>
<hr />
```

Comment: Aside from the limited browser support, `DOMNodeInserted` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) should be used instead

Comment: Unrelated. That's quite interesting how you can run the code snippet now without jsFiddle. Nice

Answer (score 3):

Same solution as Nick, without jQuery, using (the now deprecated) [MutationEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

```js
document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'IFRAME') {
      console.log("Iframe inserted into document", e);
  }
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'))
});
```

```html
<button>Add Iframe</button> <hr />
```

Since MutationEvents are deprecated, you may want to use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), note that they do require IE 11.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'))
});
  
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
   for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
     if (mutation.addedNodes[i].tagName == 'IFRAME') {
       console.log('Added IFrame', mutation.addedNodes[i]);
     }
   }
  });    
});
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(document.body, {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  characterData: false
});
```

```html
<button>Add Iframe</button> <hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) event is deprecated. You should use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead:

```js
new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  var observer = this;
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    [].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function (node) {
      if (node.nodeName === 'IFRAME') {
        alert('An iframe was inserted!');
        // if you are only interested in the first inserted iframe:
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  });    
}).observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: false // true to "observe" the whole page
});
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'))">add iframe</button>
```

MutationObservers are not implemented in some legacy browsers such as IE 10. Either tell IE users to get their stuff together and switch to Firefox, Chrome, or <s>Opera</s> Vivaldi or feature test the browser:

```
try {
    /...my code.../
} catch (e) {
    try {
        /... Nick Hermans' code.../
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Update your browser already!');
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work compared to Nicks answer.

http://codepaste.net/jzm7s3

Comment: Probably you are using IE 10 or even something worse. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome but I will try your try/catch statement.

Comment: Does the code snippet in this page work for you? I am not sure what you intention in http://codepaste.net/jzm7s3 is, because my snippet does not require any jQuery code.

Comment: When I run the code snippet within that codepaste it executes but there is no detection of an iFrame by using your code. If within the if statment I put Nicks code it works perfectly. If I use your try/catch it works but again through Nicks code.

Comment: Please post a complete self contained example to jsfiddle. Also you did not answer my question if the runnable snippet in my answer works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79438/discussion-between-bdillan-and-kay).

Comment: Nope, for a synchronous discussion I would demand a proper payment, sorry. Only asynchronous comments are for free. :)

Comment: Stack is forcing me to chat with you. I apoligize